# jQuery checkbox check/uncheck

Tags: jquery, checkbox

What would be a proper way to check/uncheck checkbox that's placed inside the element that triggers my function?

Here's my code:

```
<table id="news_list">
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="news[1]" /></td>
    <td>TEXT</td>
</tr></table>

$("#news_list tr").click(function() {
    var ele = $(this).find('input');
    if(ele.is(':checked')){
        ele.removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).removeClass('admin_checked');
    }else{
        ele.attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).addClass('admin_checked');
    }
});
```

The problem is I can check and uncheck each box only once. After I've checked and unchecked sometimes it still does add/remove class, but never checking a box again (even when I click on checkbox, not table row).

I've tried using .bind('click') trigger, but it's the same result.

Any solutions?

Comment: Looking at the answers, I'm not so sure they give a solution to what you are trying to do. I don't see why it would make sense to basically disable checkbox, which is what those given answers are doing ( Because when you click the checkbox it becomes checked and that means the if statement will immediately uncheck it... and that means you can never actually check the checkbox by clicking the actual checkbox... right? ). Is this what you are looking to do?: http://jsfiddle.net/7gbhf/

Comment: @Joonas Thanks, this is exactly what i needed! Jai's answer did work for signle row, not for multiple

Comment: Good. One thing though. If my jsfiddle is exactly what you need, I'm not sure I see how Jai's answer works for one row. It doesn't let you check the checkbox by clicking the checkbox, which is due to the if statement as I explained above. So I'm thinking that you missed that part, or... I still don't know what you wanted :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use `.prop()` instead and if we go with your code then compare like this:

Look at the example [***jsbin***](http://jsbin.com/ocolux/1/edit):

```
  $("#news_list tr").click(function () {
    var ele = $(this).find(':checkbox');
    if ($(':checked').length) {
      ele.prop('checked', false);
      $(this).removeClass('admin_checked');
    } else {
      ele.prop('checked', true);
      $(this).addClass('admin_checked');
    }
 });
```

Changes:

1. Changed `input` to `:checkbox`.
2. Comparing `the length` of the `checked checkboxes`.

Comment: `prop` didn't worked for me, but `removeAttr` and `attr` did, using jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: Thanks, prop has sorted out a different issue for me, so found this piece of info very useful.

Comment: if this doesn't work, ensure the IDs are not duplicated between elements

Comment: Thanks for the edits @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 21):

Use prop() instead of attr() to set the value of `checked`. Also use `:checkbox` in find method instead of `input` and be specific.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/rXU64/)

```
$("#news_list tr").click(function() {
    var ele = $(this).find('input');
    if(ele.is(':checked')){
        ele.prop('checked', false);
        $(this).removeClass('admin_checked');
    }else{
        ele.prop('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('admin_checked');
    }
});
```

[Use prop instead of attr for properties like checked](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead.

Comment: Actually this is the correct solution . Accepted   answer have some problem.Thank you for this solution .

Answer (score 6):

```
 $('mainCheckBox').click(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('Id or Class of checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    }else{
        $('Id or Class of checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```