# jQuery attr() function is cross-platform independant isn't

Tags: jquery, html, css, dhtml, attr

The following jQuery statement is working for me. but i don't know either it is a cross-platform independent or not?

```
$("input[name='confirmed']").attr("checked",false);
```

Its working on fire fox latest version. 
Please correct me if i am wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You can see the browser support here : http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Tip: If you want to set/get properties (like in your example), you should use `.prop()` instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769408/jquery-checkbox-check-uncheck

Comment: Yes, you are right, [link](http://api.jquery.com/attr) here i also find the same tip. thanks MelanciaUK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, JQuery is fully cross-browser compatible. Usually when something doesn't work in one [modern] browser, it won't work in any of them.

I think the most common syntax for dealing with checkboxes is thus:

```
// set checked state
$("input[name='confirmed']").prop("checked", true);

// remove checked state
$("input[name='confirmed']").prop("checked", false);

// test checked state
$("input[name='confirmed']").is(":checked"); // returns boolean

// pull out only checked inputs
$("input[name='confirmed']").filter(":checked"); // returns collection
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the function wrong, it doesn't really matter what browser support for your usage is like.

The second argument of [the `attr` method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) must be a string, a number or a function (which returns a string or a number).

If you want to remove an attribute, use [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

If you want to twiddle the checked status of an input, then [use `prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) not `attr` (`attr` sets the *default* value for the checked state, not the current value).

Answer (score 1):

use an on click event

```
if($("input[name='confirmed']").attr("checked")){
   $("input[name='confirmed']").removeAttr("checked");
} else {
   $("input[name='confirmed']").attr("checked","checked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my jQuery method attr() to prop() with this way:

```
$("input[name='confirmed']").prop("checked",false);
```

and its working fine. 
Please see the following link for reference:

http://api.jquery.com/attr

Special thanks to Mr. MelanciaUK by giving his precious hint:

Thank you all for your valuable suggestions.